# Change the background of a label when acting as checkbox

Tags: html, css

I have labels with images nested inside that is acting as a checkbox. What I can't figure out is how to change the background behind the image when that specific checkbox is selected (label clicked).

It appears as if one of the checkboxes is getting the background to show, but not both and the height element is not working.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```css
.notificationImgs {
 width: 70px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.notifCheck {
 display: none;
}
.notifCheck:checked + label {
 background: #CCC;
}
.notifCheck:checked .notificationImgs {
 background-color: #CCC;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<label for="checkText">
   <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Text Notifications" class="notificationImgs">
  </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkText" class="notifCheck" id="checkText" value="text">
  <label for="checkEmail">
   <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Email Notifications" class="notificationImgs">
  </label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not adding background on correct label because of the ordering of `input` and `label`. Put related `input` (which is hidden checkbox) before the related label. So `.notifCheck:checked + label` can find the correct `label`. Also you can add `display:inline-block` to all `label` style. So it will resolve the height issue.

See the Snippet below:

```css
.notificationImgs {
 width: 70px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.notifCheck {
 display: none;
}
label{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
}
.notifCheck:checked + label {
 background: #CCC;
}
.notifCheck:checked .notificationImgs {
 background-color: #CCC;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkText" class="notifCheck" id="checkText" value="text">
<label for="checkText">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Text Notifications" class="notificationImgs">
</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkEmail" class="notifCheck" id="checkEmail" value="text">
<label for="checkEmail">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Email Notifications" class="notificationImgs">
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the altered HTML/code for you. You were missing checkbox and your CSS is `+` selector which is looking for checked + label so for first checkbox it was targeting second label.

```css
.notificationImgs {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.notifCheck {
  display: none;
}

.notifCheck:checked+label {
  background: #CCC;
}

.notifCheck:checked .notificationImgs {
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}

label{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkText" class="notifCheck" id="checkText" value="text">
<label for="checkText">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Text Notifications" class="notificationImgs"/>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkText" class="notifCheck" id="checkEmail" value="text">
<label for="checkEmail">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Email Notifications" class="notificationImgs"/>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I get the new background to cover the full height of the image?

Comment: That's a different concern from your main question.

Answer (score 1):

Label should come after checkbox in your case.

```css
label{
 display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    background: #eee;
}
.notificationImgs {
 width: 70px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.notifCheck {
 display: none;
}
.notifCheck:checked + label {
 background: #aaa;
}
.notifCheck:checked .notificationImgs {
 background-color: #aaa;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkText" class="notifCheck" id="checkText" value="text">
<label for="checkText">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Text Notifications" class="notificationImgs">
</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkEmail" class="notifCheck" id="checkEmail" value="text">
<label for="checkEmail">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Email Notifications" class="notificationImgs">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, you only have one checkbox input present. The 2nd label indicates you most likely meant to include a 2nd input checkbox with the id of #checkEmail.

The space (descendant selector) only selects all elements that are 'descendants of a specified element.
So, `.notifCheck:checked .notificationImgs` does not compute because `notificationImgs` is not a descendant of `notifCheck`.

The '+' (adjacent sibling selector) only selects elements that are are adjacent siblings. 
So, `notifCheck:checked + label` is only selecting the 2nd label element, as this element immediately follows the `.notifCheck` element.